# ¿Cómo modifico los valores que trae php en formato json desde angular?

Tags: php, html, json, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="practica">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="buscar" placeholder="Buscar">
<div ng-controller="ctrldatos">
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Sub Categoria Codigo</th>
  <th>Sub Categoria Nombre</th>
  <th>Sub Categoria</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:buscar ">
  <td>{{x.subcat_cod}}</td>
  <td>{{x.subcat_nom}}</td>
  <td>{{x.cat_cod}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module("practica",[])
  .controller("ctrldatos",function($scope,$http){
  $http.get("get.php")
  .success(function (response)
  {
   $scope.names = response;
  });
 });
</script>
</html>


Como puedo modificar los valores que trae php en formato json usando angular:
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module("practica",[])
    .controller("ctrldatos",function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("get.php")
        .success(function (response)
        {
            $scope.names = response;
        });
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: Quisiera cambiar los datos que me trae PHP , lo que hago por ahora es mostrar todo los datos , pero lo que quiero es cambiarlo con una condicional que si el valor tal  que me trae PHP es tanto cambiarlo y mostrarl el nuevo valor en una de las expresiones

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo del valor devuelto por PHP y un ejemplo de valor que deseas cambiar?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías trabajar el dato que obtienes del `$http` en un `angular.forEach` para iterar cada valor y aplicar la condición que cambien el valor de cada item.

En este ejemplo

```
.controller("ctrldatos",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("get.php")
    .success(function (response)
    {
        angular.forEach(response, function(value, key){
            if(value.subcat_cod == "1")
                value.subcat_nom = "otrovalor";
        });

        $scope.names = response;
    });
});
```

imagine que si la subcategoria tenia un valor cambiar el nombre, por supuesto es solo un ejemplo que deberias adaptar.

---

También podrías ayudarte con librerías como ser [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)

Esta cuenta con funciones como ser el `_.map()` para poder convertir cada item de una lista en otra diferentes.